# license-maven-plugin: Include missing licenses in dependency report

Tags: java, maven, licensing

I have a multi-module build with quite some dependencies. Each subproject has its own dependencies report and there is one project that depends (transitively) on all the other projects. Now there are many dependencies that are missing licensing information. I would like to include all these missing licenses in the dependency report. But I can't seem to get this working. Does anyone have suggestions?

What I am currently trying is:

- In the parent project, I defined various third party license like "eula", "potix_eula", "bsd_pgsql", ... in src/license by adding subdirectories with these names
- In these directories I have the header.txt and license.txt files for the licenses
- in this src/license directory I have a licenses.properties with entries such as "potix_eula=potix_eula"
- in this src/license directory I also have a licenses.xml with entries like

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
>   <artifactId>jdbc4</artifactId>
>   <licenses><license><name>bsd_pgsql</name></license></licenses>
> </dependency>
> ```

- In the parent project's pom I configure the license-maven-plugin:

> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
> <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
> <version>1.5</version>
> <configuration>         
>       <useMissingFile>true</useMissingFile>
>       <licensesConfigFile>C:/eclipse-workspace-kepler/TheParentProject/src/license/licenses.xml</licensesConfigFile>
>       <licenseName>zk_potix_eula</licenseName>
>       <licenseName>bsd_pgsql</licenseName>
>       <licenseResolver>file://${project.basedir}/src/license</licenseResolver>
>       <licenseMerges>...</licenseMerges> 
>     </configuration>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>           <id>first</id>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>update-file-header</goal>
>           </goals>
>           <phase>process-sources</phase>
>         </execution>
>           <execution>
>             <id>download-licenses</id>
>             <phase>process-resources</phase>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>download-licenses</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         <execution>
>           <id>add-third-party</id>
>           <phase>process-resources</phase>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>aggregate-add-third-party</goal>
>           </goals>
>         </execution>
>       </executions>
>      </plugin>
> ```

- I have generated THIRD-PARTY.properties in all projects and defined the licenses like this: commons.apache.org--commons-configuration--1.7=apache_v2
- I have also tried copying the src/license directory from the parent into all the src directories of the modules. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I see, I forgot to include the third-parties report that contains all the required information.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <useMissingFile>true</useMissingFile>
      <useRepositoryMissingFiles>true</useRepositoryMissingFiles>
        <licenseName>zk_potix_eula</licenseName>
        <licenseName>bsd_pgsql</licenseName>
        <licenseName>bsd_hamcrest</licenseName>
        <licenseName>bsd_dom4j</licenseName>
        <licenseResolver>file://${project.parent.basedir}/src/license</licenseResolver>
        <licenseMerges>
          <licenseMerge>Apache 2.0|The Apache Software License, Version 2.0|Apache License, Version 2.0|apache_v2</licenseMerge>
          <licenseMerge>CDDL 1.0|COMMON DEVELOPMENT AND DISTRIBUTION LICENSE (CDDL) Version 1.0|Common Development and Distribution License (CDDL) v1.0|cddl_v1</licenseMerge>
          <licenseMerge>GNU LGPL 2.1|GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), Version 2.1|GNU Lesser General Public License, version 2.1|lgpl_v2_1</licenseMerge>
          <licenseMerge>GNU LGPL 3|GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 3|GNU Lesser General Public Licence|GNU Lesser General Public License|GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE</licenseMerge>
          <licenseMerge>Dual license: CDDL 1.0 and GPL v2|Dual license consisting of the CDDL v1.0 and GPL v2|CDDL+GPLv2|CDDL+GPL|CDDL+GPL License</licenseMerge>
          <licenseMerge>Dual license: CDDL 1.1 and GPL v2|Dual license consisting of the CDDL v1.1 and GPL v2|CDDL1_1+GPLv2</licenseMerge>
          <licenseMerge>Dual License: CDDL 1.0 and GPL V2 with Classpath Exception|CDDL + GPLv2 with classpath exception</licenseMerge>
        </licenseMerges> 
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: For anyone wondering: Introducing `<useMissingFile>true</useMissingFile>` introduced one error per dependency. Once I added the missing license name to the generated file `src/license/THIRD-PARTY.properties` the errors disappeared. I initially thought that this setting broke something but apparently its just an error that is not catched properly. (v1.17)